# SARIMA model order

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, arima

I am using SARIMA model (1,1,1)(2,1,1,96) for a dataset with ACF and PACF plots as follows:
 [ACF plot of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqpR7.png)
[PACF plot of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiBLp.png)

After using the mentioned model, I look into the ACF and PACF plots to make sure that I have covered all the dependencies; however, the ACF and PACF plots show a large value at lag 96. I would appreciate it if I get some help about the modifications that I should make to my SARIMA model order. Please consider that my data has a daily seasonality and since it is 15 min data, S=96.

[ACF and PACF plots after fitting the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRGTv.png)

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [auto_arima function in pmdarima package](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.auto_arima.html) to iterate over combinations of orders and get the best value based on AIC score.You have identified seasonal and non-seasonal orders looking at acf and pacf plots.You can use those orders as starting parameters.

```
import pmdarima as pm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
model = pm.auto_arima(<train_data>,error_action="ignore", suppress_warnings = True,
                         seasonal = True,
                         m = 96,
                         start_p = 1,start_q = 1,d=1,
                         start_P = 2,start_Q = 1,D=1,
                         max_p = 12,max_q = 12,max_d=2,
                         max_P = 4,max_Q = 4,max_D = 2,
                         test='adf', #use adf test
                         information_criterion='aic', #AIC or BIC
                         stepwise = False, trace = False)
```

After that you can get the model diagnostics using `plot_diagnostics` function

```
model.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(8,8))
```

also you can get the  [Ljung-Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) and [Jarque-Bera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test) statistics from summary function to  check the distribution of residuals and correlation of residuals.

```
model.summary()
```